# Figures in subfigure not aligned

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, subfloats

I have 2 figures identical in size, I even aligned them myself in Illustrator, just to be sure, and when I put them in subfigure side by side, they are not horizontally aligned!

The worst part is, I have 2 other pictures, again the same size, and they are aligned normally. And the code is the same!! I don't know what's the problem!! Is there a way to manually shift one picture up a bit?

Here's the MWE:

```
%&latex
\documentclass[twocolumn,prc,floats,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,11pt]{revtex4-1}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcolumntype{y}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!tp]
       \centering
       \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
               \centering
               \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{Cobalt60.eps}
               \label{fig:Co}
       \end{subfigure}\quad
       \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
               \centering
               \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{Cezij137.eps}
               \label{fig:Cs}
       \end{subfigure}
       \caption{Lijevo: Spektar ${}^{60} \textrm{Co}$ s dvije karakteristične zrake na 1173.237 keV i 1332.501 keV. Desno: Spektar ${}^{137} \textrm{Cs}$ s karakterističnom zrakom na 661.657 keV. Na manjoj slici je uvećan Comptonov rub smješten oko 550-og kanala.}
       \label{fig:Spektripoz1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[!tp]
       \centering
       \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
               \centering
               \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{Barij133.eps}
               \label{fig:Ba}
       \end{subfigure}\quad
       \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
               \centering
               \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{fit.eps}
       \end{subfigure}
       \caption{Lijevo: Spektar ${}^{133} \textrm{Ba}$. Barijev spektar ima nekoliko karakterističnih vrhova, no uzimamo samo najintenzivniji vrh. Desno: Kalibracijski pravac.}
       \label{fig:Spektripoz2}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

And here are the pictures (.eps format):

http://www76.zippyshare.com/v/19000331/file.html
http://www76.zippyshare.com/v/78211264/file.html
http://www76.zippyshare.com/v/46193895/file.html
http://www76.zippyshare.com/v/25153661/file.html

The second right picture is lower than the left, and the first pictures are perfectly aligned...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the code it is obvious what the difference between the two floats is: the labels! Since you don't have sub-captions, remove the `\label` commands for them, and the alignment problem disappears.

Comment: Omg I'm such an idiot! i totally didn't notice that there is no label under the second one (and I don't need labels in subfigures anyway)! Feels dumb xD

Thanks!!!! :)

Comment: Nonono, this happens. But maybe @AxelSommerfeldt might have a look into this, as the `\label` seems to leak something into the float.

Comment: I have the same problem but I do have subcaptions and my figures are not aligned (one is smaller than the other and this causes the subcaptions to not be aligned). How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I did solve my problem by substituting `\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}` by `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}`

Comment: @kalmanlsAGameChanger thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For those that run into this issue but do have subcaptions (like me): I found that the solution was to use `\begin{subfigure}[t]{<width>}`: using `t` in the argument being passed into `subfigure` apparently aligns images at the top rather than the bottom (`b`), meaning the tops of the images and captions are aligned and the bottoms of the captions can flow as far as they want without affecting the rest of the layout!

([source](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24598))