# Align figure and tables in subfigure environment

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, subfig

I am trying to put a table and a figure side by side with a subfigure environment. I followed some resources online and the most similar is the following: [Join figure and table on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/join-figure-and-table-on-the-same-page). In particular, I am referring to the third answer, however, I cannot apply that solution as in the document I already have some subfigure environments and thus I cannot use the subcaption package.

That the code example:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Without cleaning.]{
            \begin{tabular}{lr}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Class Label} & \textbf{Frequency} \\ \midrule
                ON                    & 54.14\%            \\ 
                OFF                    & 41.43\%            \\ 
                WEAK                 & 3.33\%             \\ 
                S/OFF                & 1.1\%              \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \label{tab-freq-complete}}
        \quad \quad
        \subfloat[With cleaning.]{
            \begin{tabular}{lr}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Class Label} & \textbf{Frequency} \\ \midrule
                ON                    & 56.64\%            \\ 
                OFF                    & 43.36\%            \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \label{tab-freq-two}}
        \caption{Label frequencies across all the dataset.}
    \end{table}


    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Accuracy and F1-scores.]{
            \begin{tabular}{lr}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Score} \\ \midrule
                Accuracy        & 56.64\%        \\ 
                F1 for ON       & 72.32\%        \\ 
                F1 for OFF      & 0\%            \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \label{res-ma}}
        \subfloat[Confusion matrix.]{           
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{../../data-visualization/confusion_matrix_ma} 

            \label{fig:ma}          

            }
        \caption{Majority classifier results.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, with my code the figure is not vertically aligned with the table. I try also with that solution: [Figures in subfigure not aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102251/figures-in-subfigure-not-aligned), but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the alingment you would like to achieve (bottom, centered, top), you could choose from one of the examples liste below. They all use the `valign` option of the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Accuracy and F1-scores.]{
            \adjustbox{valign=b}{\begin{tabular}{lr}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Score} \\ \midrule
                Accuracy        & 56.64\%        \\ 
                F1 for ON       & 72.32\%        \\ 
                F1 for OFF      & 0\%            \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \label{res-ma}}}
        \subfloat[Confusion matrix.]{           
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,valign=b]{example-image} 

            \label{fig:ma}          

            }
        \caption{Majority classifier results.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Accuracy and F1-scores.]{
            \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{tabular}{lr}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Score} \\ \midrule
                Accuracy        & 56.64\%        \\ 
                F1 for ON       & 72.32\%        \\ 
                F1 for OFF      & 0\%            \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \label{res-ma}}}
        \subfloat[Confusion matrix.]{           
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image} 

            \label{fig:ma}          

            }
        \caption{Majority classifier results.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Accuracy and F1-scores.]{
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tabular}{lr}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Score} \\ \midrule
                Accuracy        & 56.64\%        \\ 
                F1 for ON       & 72.32\%        \\ 
                F1 for OFF      & 0\%            \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \label{res-ma}}}
        \subfloat[Confusion matrix.]{           
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} 

            \label{fig:ma}          

            }
        \caption{Majority classifier results.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar problem when trying to align a figure and a table side-by-side.

And here is a successful sample using `\subfigure`:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{xxx.pdf}
\caption{A Figure}
\label{fig}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     xx & xx \\ 
     xx & xx \\ 
\end{tabular}
\caption{A Table}
\label{table}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A Table & A Figure} 
\end{figure*}
```

Note that the align position in `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}` needs to be `[b]` instead of `[t]` for both subfigures. (I don't know why but in my case, when setting them to `[t]`, the figure and the table cannot be correctly aligned).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!